# using dijit.byId w dojox.mobile widgets

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I'm dynamically building a series of dojox.mobile.ListItem widgets under a statically defined dojox.mobile.RoundRectList widget via this function...

```
function displayOpps(items) {

// Create the list container that will hold application names
var rrlOppsContainer = dijit.byId("rrlOpps");   
// Add a new item to the list container for each element in the server respond
for (var i in items){

    // Create and populate the list container with applications' names
    var name = items[i].CustName + " - " + items[i].OppNbr;
    var liOpps = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        label: name,
        moveTo: "sv3OppDetail"  
    });

    // Add the newly created item to the list container
    rrlOppsContainer.addChild(liOpps);
}
```

}

When I run this code during onLoad() in my html file, I get the following error using Chrome's dev tools...

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'byId'

I've read numerous articles around this topic and it appears that lots of folks have this problem, but each that I have found are in relation to some other technology (e.g., Spring MVC, etc) and I'm attempting to use it w a dojox.mobile based app.  That said, I attempted to mimic some of the solutions brought up by others by including this in my html file, and it still doesn't work...

```
<script type="text/javascript"
data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"
src="dojo/dojo.js">
dojo.require("dojox.mobile.RoundRectList")
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Dojo 1.7+, you probably just forgot to require the "dijit/registry" module. This where the byId function is defined. When you use desktop widgets, this is loaded indirectly by other base modules, but with dojox/mobile you must load it explicitly (because dojox/mobile loads only a very minimal set of modules by default, to minimize code footprint).

Depending on how you wrote your application, do this:

```
dojo.require("dijit.registry");  // legacy (pre-1.7) loader syntax
...
var rrlOppsContainer = dijit.byId("rrlOpps");
...
```

or this:

```
require(["dijit/registry", ...], function(registry, ...){ // 1.7+ AMD loader syntax
    ...
    var rrlOppsContainer = registry.byId("rrlOpps");
    ...
});
```

Note also that your second code sample tries to use asynchronous loading (async: true) while it uses the legacy loader syntax. This won't work, to get async loading you must use the AMD syntax.

Comment: hmmmm... I changed the async param to false, then added the legacy syntax of dojo.require("dijit.registry"); as suggested, and the error still occurs.  As I said before, I've seen many functioning examples of this so I believe that I have some other error that's preventing the dijit package from being loaded.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I found my problem... I mixed legacy and AMD syntax.  Thank you for your time and expertise.